# Inappropriate closure of heatmap question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659178/how-heatmaps-really-work/10659233#10659233

was closed, I strongly believe inappropriately.  The reason for the closure given was that it's not a "good fit for the question and answer format", but the question asked

- is specific: "Is a heatmap suited for this kind of visualization? How is one built?"
- has a definite, algorithmic answer: "map vertices to colors using a rule; interpolate for zooming or missing points"
- leads to references to more extensive information.

The closure was clearly an oversight and in error.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it doesn't really seem on-topic though. What is the programming problem the OP wants help with? Asking "how heatmaps work" does not really seem to fit the bill. And the "java" and "javascript" tags don't do much to help the question either.

Comment: I closed this because it falls firmly into discussion territory.

Comment: Good answer to a poorly framed question.

Comment: Belongs on programmers meta?

Comment: Kev, it doesn't.  Very explicit question with, as you saw, a specific answer.  I've ranted this rant before, the the purpose of these sites is to provide useful information, not prove that we're smarter than the questioners.  If we *can* understand the question, we should answer, or edit, or comment in ways that *help* get to a good answer, instead of saying "a-ha, my moderator-fu can defeat you!"

Comment: @Rosinante I thought that, too, but the question was originally asked on Stack Overflow. It was only migrated to Programmers after a Programmers mod saw this conversation here and said they'd take it.

Answer (score 5):

> - is specific: "Is a heatmap suited for this kind of visualization? How is one built?"
> - has a definite, algorithmic answer: "map vertices to colors using a rule; interpolate for zooming or missing points"
> - leads to references to more extensive information.

Yet, it received this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659288/99456) (which currently stands at +2):

> If you want an opensource library and do the processing on the client, [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) works well. Here is a demo of a [heatmap on Google Maps](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/demo/maps_heatmap_layer/gmaps.php)

I really like [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659233/99456) *and* your interpretation of the question. However you must admit that since the other answer seems to be answering a completely different question, it's possible that the question isn't so specific after all. And we aren't talking about a typical trolling answer, this is an answer by a 16K rep user that two people thought was worthy of their up vote.

To cut a long story short, if you (or anyone else) is willing to do some minor edits to the question to bring it a little closer to your interpretation of it, I think it will fit nicely on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions), were we enjoy a tiny bit of subjectivity (every once in a while). The first edit was already made, the irrelevant tags that might have misled the other answerer were removed.

Comment: Just gave the question a tweek to fit the main answer better.

Comment: Thanks @Mat, the question is now on Programmers.